# Standard Normal Distribution Transformation Z=lnY

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I'm not sure if my approach to this problem is correct and I need help

I need to apply $Z=\ln{Y}$ to the following standard normal distribution and then find the distribution of $Y$

$f(z)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}}~$

my approach was like this

$z=\ln{y}$

$y=e^z$

$dz=\frac1{y}dy$

then the distribution of $Y$ is

$f(y)=\frac1{y\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(\ln{y})^2}{2}}$

is my approach correct?

I am a beginner at statistics and I want to get better so any help is welcomed

Comment: Please rewrite the pair of PDFs in your question, at present both RHS are numbers, not functions.

Comment: I have changed them into functions

Answer (score 0):

If $Z \text{~}N(0,1)$ variable with $Y=e^Z$.

Then $ F_Y(y) = Pr(Y<y) = Pr(e^Z<y) = Pr(Z<ln(y)) = F_Z(ln(y)) $ ) ,

Now note that $ S_Z = (-\infty,\infty) $ , so $ S_Y = (0,\infty)  $.
Hence,

$
F_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
F_Z(ln(y)),  & \text{if  }{y \in (0,\infty)} \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$

Then observe that the pdf of Y is 
$ 
f_Y(y) = 
{ dF_Y(y) \over dy } = 
\begin{cases}
{ dF_Z(ln(y)) \over dy } , & \text{if  }{y \in (0,\infty)}, \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}= 
\begin{cases}
{ { 1 \over y }{ f_Z(ln(y)) } } , & \text{if  }{y \in (0,\infty)}, \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}= 
\begin{cases}
{ 1 \over { y\sqrt { 2\pi } } }{ e^{-(ln(y))^2 \over 2 } }, & \text{if  }{y \in (0,\infty)}, \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases},$
(what you got).

So yes the approach is correct-ish, what I meant before is that you didn't have the correct structure. What I said before about the distribution, ignore... I had a derp moment.. >.<"

Comment: So I got the answer correct but I didn't have the theory behind it. I am always confused by cdf and pdf, thanks for the clarification.

and don't worry about latex I can understand you answer perfectly, I was just wondering when you wrote H(y)=P(Y did you just forget to close the bracket?

Comment: Yes now you did. Good thing you changed the functions.

Comment: Oh no, my phone lagged and deleted my stuff, sorry